# How to draw marks on Unity 3D plane?

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, draw

I am new to Unity. Sorry if I have a beginner style of question.

I want to implement a 3D Chess game in Unity. I have already implemented a C++ shared library that contains the whole AI thing. I have used this library in WPF and Android and it is tested perfectly. Now it is Unity's turn.

When the user selects a piece, next moves of it should be shown.

[image: Chessboard image]

These marks can be a light or image. Circular or rectangle.

One way to do this is to have 64 marks per each square of the Chess board and change their visibility programmatically.

The other way, which I personally prefer, is to draw the marks programmatically. But I don't know how to draw on my Chessboard plane.

Please guide me with it.

Comment: You should not do the drawing, that would mean redrawing the chess texture for each move. Quite memory consuming. The other process could be to use the projector with an additive shader.

Comment: @Everts I have searched a little but I have not found a good reference to read. Can you give me a link?

Comment: What do you mean by marks ? Can you put a picture of what a simple mark on the chess board is supposed to look like?

Comment: I have a couple possible answers, but it really depends on how it needs to look and act.  I'd like to see a mockup.

Comment: @Programmer I have added an Image as you wanted.

Comment: @Richjoslin I have added an Image as you wanted.

Comment: You should not try to hard on this. I would add quad Renderer to each chess section and activate it when needed. You need to think whether the time it takes to develop something better is worth the run.

Comment: Just finished a way to do this programmatically code and texture only but realized that you found your solution.

Comment: @Programmer let me read and decide which one is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**FINAL RESULT** (Just a sketchup!)

[image]

**STEP BY STEP**:

*(I assume you have already had a chessboard)*

**1.** Create a Material & configure it like in the below image. Note that the albedo green is 50% transparent:

[image]

**2.** Create a Quad & assign it the newly created Material above. Then set
    it up like in the below image:

[image]

**3.** Now we will add the glow effect. First, we need to turn off the
    Anti-Aliasing by switching to `Good Quality` instead of `Fantastic`.

[image]

**4.** Second, we need to enable `HDR` in the main camera:

[image]

**5.** Third, we need to import the `Image Effects` package. This package
    is part of the `Standard Assets` that is shipped with Unity. It is
    completely free. Get it here if you haven't.
    https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/32351
You only need the `Image Effect` package.

[image]

**6.** Now add the `Bloom` effect to your main camera.

[image]

**7.** That's it! If you need to hide it via code then get the reference to
    it and execute this line of code:

`yourQuad.SetActive(false);`

See more here:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.SetActive.html

**8.** Finally, duplicate that quad to create 64 ones & position them
    properly. There are 2 tricks that can help your life in hell a lot
    easier:

**To quickly duplicate a group of objects**: select all of them and press: `Ctrl + D`

**To enable edge-snap**: select your quad and hold down `V` then hover your mouse over the quad's vertex. You will see a white square around it. Drag that vetex and see the magic.

**9.** From this on, it is your game logic to implement. You could store
    all the quads in a 2-dimensional `array` (matrix) and manipulate it
    yourself, that it all I can think of. Goodluck!

Comment: How about using Standard Specular shader and skip step 3 to 6?

Comment: @Everts: I've just tried it! Actually, I haven't found a way to achieve the glow effect without `bloom`. `HDR` is just for making the `bloom` nicer but it requires turning off the `Anti-Aliasing`. `Specular` is just a way to replace `metallic` workflow. If you use Standard shader, you are given a `metallic` slider. If you use `Standard (Specular setup)` shader that slider is replaced with `Specular` one.